# Make Retrofit API call in Activity using Kotlin coroutines

Tags: android, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

I want to load some data inside activity after the button is clicked. I came up with the following solution and it works as I expect. But I just started learning kotlin coroutines and I want someone else to comment on my code. For example, is it okay that I update the UI using `lifecycleScope.launch`? I could probably use `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)` instead but is there a difference?

Is my implementation good in general? Is there something that could be optimzed/refactored?

I understand that it's better to use ViewModel and make API calls there but in this case I want all action to happen inside the activity.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var apiCallScope: CoroutineScope? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        findViewById<View>(R.id.btn_load_content).setOnClickListener {
            // Cancel previous API call triggered by the click.
            // I don't want to have multiple API calls executing at the same time.
            apiCallScope?.cancel()

            showProgress(true)

            apiCallScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
            apiCallScope!!.launch {
                // Execute Retrofit API call
                val content = api.loadContent().await()

                // Update UI with the content from API call on main thread
                lifecycleScope.launch {
                    showProgress(false)
                    drawContent(content)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        apiCallScope?.cancel()
    }

    private fun showProgress(show: Boolean) {
        // TODO implement
    }

    private fun drawContent(content: String) {
        // TODO implement
    }

}
```

Comment: I guess this question belongs to this channel https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

It's preferable to use ViewModel to make such types of operations and not perform them inside Activity, especially in the onCreate method.

ViewModel gives you the viewModelScope property, any coroutine launched in this scope is automatically canceled if the ViewModel is cleared to avoid consuming resources.